# Python replace forward slash with back slash

Tags: python, regex

I have

```
foo = '/DIR/abc'
```

and I want to convert it to

```
bar = '\\MYDIR\data\abc'
```

So, here's what I do in Python:

```
>>> foo = '/DIR/abc'
>>> bar = foo.replace(r'/DIR/',r'\\MYDIR\data\')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    bar = foo.replace(r'/DIR/',r'\\MYDIR\data\')
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

If, however, I try to escape the last backslash by entering instead `bar = foo.replace(r'/DIR/',r'\\MYDIR\data\\')`, then I get this monstrosity:

```
>>> bar2
'\\\\MYDIR\\data\\\\abc'
```

Help! This is driving me insane.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python raw literal string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517802/python-raw-literal-string)

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=leaning+toothpick+syndrome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second argument should be a string, not a regex pattern:

```
foo.replace(r'/DIR/', '\\\\MYDIR\\data\\')
```

Comment: I get `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` when running your code.

Comment: Woops, sorry.  I  missed the last `\ ` again, just like you :P

Comment: Now the result is `'\\\\MYDIR\\data\\abc'`

Comment: You answer is not correct. The second argument will generate the same SyntaxError because you're trying to end the string with a single backslash, which is treated is the string "\'"

Comment: @synaptik If you're seeing that in the python REPL, it prints escaped strings automatically.  Try `print '\\\\MYDIR\data\\abc'` to get the value you seek

Comment: @Manfre seems to work fine for me.  I tested it out.  Also, the string is not ending with a single backslash

Comment: Your edit and my comment crossed. I'm now seeing it with the fix.

Comment: @Manfre yeah it was a dumb copy/paste error by me in the first place

Comment: @ExplosionPills You're actually escaping the `d` in this code, luckily `\d` isn't valid so it doesn't show but you should fix it.

Comment: @Serdalis I disagree; why add more characters that aren't needed?

Comment: @ExplosionPills You are effectively attempting to escape an invalid character, that in itself is reason enough to add another slash. We aren't working on floppy based machines anymore, your computer can handle a bit of correctness.

Answer (score 4):

I simply put a `r` in front of `/` to change the forward slash.

```
inv_num = line.replace(r'/', '-')
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are encountering this is because of the behavior of the `r""` syntax, Taking some explanation from the [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

> r"\"" is a valid string literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote; r"\" is not a valid string literal (even a raw string cannot end in an odd number of backslashes). Specifically, a raw string cannot end in a single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following quote character).

So you will need to use a normal escaped string for the last argument.

```
>>> foo = "/DIR/abc"
>>> print foo.replace(r"/DIR/", "\\\\MYDIR\\data\\")
\\MYDIR\data\abc
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. A raw literal simply cannot end with a single backslash because it is interpreted as escaping the quote character. Therefore, use a regular (non-raw) literal with escapes: `'\\\\MYDIR\\data\\'`.
2. When displayed (using the `repr` style), strings will appear with escapes. Therefore, `'\\\\'` only has two actual backslashes. So, `'\\\\MYDIR\\data\\\\abc'` is really `\\MYDIR\data\\abc`.

Answer (score 0):

path=path.replace(r"/","\") will replace path=C:/folder with path=C:\folder

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).