# Python xlsxwriter, export to a network drive

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I am wanting to export my .xlsx file to a network drive. I am currently doing this as below:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('z:/Company drive/Checking/Monthly Checks.xlsx')
```

I want my colleagues to be able to use this software and would be ideal if they did not have to remap the drive to Z:.

Is it possible to export to a path like "\servername\Checking\Monthly Checks.xlsx"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use a UNC path instead of a mapped drive.

I would recommend putting the `r'...'` string literal modifier in front ([link to an answer with a detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517802/python-raw-literal-string)).

So your code would be
`workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'\\servername\Company drive\Checking\Monthly Checks.xlsx')` 
instead of  `workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('\\servername\Company drive\Checking\Monthly Checks.xlsx')`